# How to change string s to char * a[]?

Tags: c++

I want to transform

`string s="aaa,bbb,ccc"`

into:

`char * a[]={"aaa", "bbb", "ccc"}`

Could you help me how to program for dealing with this process?

**I will try to program like this:**

```
string s="aaa,bbb,ccc";
char * a[];
char id[] = "";
strcpy(id, s.c_str());
const char * split = ",";
char * p;

    p = strtok(id, split);
    while (p != NULL) {
        int i = 0;
        printf("%s\n", p);
        a[i]=p;

        i++;
        p = strtok(NULL, split);
    }
```

**where is my wrong? who can point out ?**

Comment: You can't, the dimensions of `a` need to be known at compile time.

Comment: but i can't confirm the dimensions of s. maybe  s ="aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,..." so I hope  slicing by ","

Comment: check Boost Tokenizer http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/tokenizer/

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: the string s come from config.ini   ,i fopen  the config.ini  use string s transform into char *a[]={"","",""}  for my function call it  .my function is  subdata(a)

Comment: Did you write this function `subdata`? Can you change it, or must you conform to an existing interface? Can you show us the declaration of `subdata`?

Comment: the subdata() is defined by third party ,i just  reference it .
 subdata( char *  ppInstrumentID[],  
  int  nCount  
 )

Answer (score 2):

I'm new to programming, but I've been doing the following:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{       
    std::string s = "aaa,bbb,ccc";

    // dynamically allocate memory for the char
    char * a = new char [s.length()+1];

    // the string needs to be copied into a
    std::strcpy(a, s.c_str());

    std::cout << a;

    // cleanup
    delete [] a;

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: Just noticed you want the different parts of the string as elements of the char array, my answer doesn't do that.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use a `std::vector<std::string>` to store your results instead of `char* []`, it should be more useful.

So, try [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/236803/649322), purely C++ std library.

But if you surely need a `char* []`, I suggest that write a converter function,
, like:

```
char** ToCharArrays(const std::vector<std::string>& strings)
{
    char** cs = new char* [strings.size()];
    for (int i = 0, l = strings.size(); i < l; ++i)
    {
        cs[i] = const_cast<char*>(strings[i].c_str());
    }
    return cs;
}
```

Use case is like this:

```
std::string input("aaa,bbb,ccc");
std::vector<std::string> strings = Split(input, ',');
char** asCharArrays = ToCharArrays(strings);
YourAPINeedsCharArrays(asCharArrays, strings.size());
delete[] asCharArrays;
```